# Error 1002 in applescript that uses "key code" when called from macOS app

Tags: swift, macos, permissions, applescript, keystroke

I'm trying to run an AppleScript from my macOS app (Mojave, Xcode 10.3). However, when the AppleScript is run from the app, I get this error:

`/Users/my_username/Desktop/test_apple_script.scpt: execution error: System Events got an error: osascript is not allowed to send keystrokes. (1002)`

Based on other posts, I have made sure that my app can control my computer (System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility), and it also has control over System Events (System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Automation).

Here is my AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 48 using {command down}
end tell
```

The script works when run in Script Editor (I only had to give Script Editor the access in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility).

This is the code I am using to run the Apple Script from my app (via `osascript`):

```
let proc = Process()
proc.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
proc.arguments = ["/usr/bin/osascript","/Users/my_username/Desktop/test_apple_script.scpt"]
proc.launch()
```

This code works perfectly when I run a simple AppleScript that just displays a notification:

```
tell application "System Events"
    display dialog "Test"
end tell
```

How can I make it so that my AppleScript runs from my macOS app just as it does when I run it in Script Editor?

**Edit:** For some more context, the command tab case here is just an example. I am trying to find a generalizable approach to simulating keyboard shortcuts by clicking buttons in my app (e.g., the user clicks on the "cut" button and the app acts as if the user has just pressed command + x). There may be a better approach to this than using an AppleScript, but I know that it is possible to do what I want using AppleScripts.

**Edit:** In case it wasn't clear from my original question, the simple AppleScript that displays a notification was already working from within my app. The problem arises when I try to run an AppleScript that simulates user input from the keyboard.

**Edit:** This code here worked for me temporarily, but it no longer works. I did not change the code at all. I simply ran my app again.

```
let PlayPauseScript = "tell application \"Spotify\"\n playpause\n end tell"\"test\"\n end tell"
if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: PlayPauseScript) {
    scriptObject.executeAndReturnError(nil)
}
```

**Edit:** 
Here is where the problem currently stands. Based on suggestions, I added this to my `info.plist`, and now the Spotify AppleScript consistently works (when called via NSAppleScript):

```
<key>NSAppleEventsUsageDescription</key> 
<string>...this is why I need permission...</string>
```

It seems my problem (now) is just with AppleScripts that use System Events. Despite making sure that both my app and `osascript` are allowed to control my computer (via security & privacy > privacy > accessibility), I now get the same error (1002) when using `NEAppleScript` and `osascript`. My app is also allowed to control System Events (security & privacy > privacy > automation). The `osascript` error prints to the console in Xcode, and I uncovered the error code for `NEAppleScript` by using this code (in the @IBAction of the button):

```
let script =
"""
try
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "c" using {command down}
    end tell
on error errMsg number errorNumber
    display dialog "An unknown error occurred:  " & errorNumber as text
end try
"""

if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: script) {
    scriptObject.executeAndReturnError(nil)
}
```

The above code caused this to appear in the dialog box:
`An unknown error occurred: 1002`

When my app is run, it does prompt me to give it control over System Events, which I always do. My app is not sandboxed. I believe that both `NSAppleScript` and `oascript` *did* work for me once, but stopped working when I ran the app again (despite my not having made any changes to my code, I'm almost positive).

I don't know if this is informative, but the only other clue I have as to what might be going on is that I keep having to check and uncheck Script Editor's permission in `security & privacy > privacy > accessibility` to get it to run these AppleScripts because it tells me that Script Editor is not allowed to send keystrokes.

Comment: If the app is sandboxed you cannot run scripts with `Process`.

Comment: Good point. However, my app is not sandboxed.

Comment: Did you add the `NSAppleEventsUsageDescription` in Info.plist? By the way why don't you run the script with `NSAppleScript` rather than performing the shell detour.

Comment: Can you provide more context, please. Why do you need to simulate *command-tab*? it seems to me there are simpler and more efficient ways of doing that from swift than running an AppleScript through osascript. (and there are better ways of running applescripts, anyway, like NSAppleScript). But until I know context I can't really tell.

Comment: @vadian, I just threw this into Info.plist:    `<key>NSAppleEventsUsageDescription</key>
<string>NSApplication</string>`. Is that the correct way to add that? (I'm still really new to this.) And I'm looking into using NSAppleScript.

Comment: I know this is going to sound ridiculous, but you may want to check that System Events.app is in the list of applications which are granted Accessibility and Full Disk Access permissions.  After that, you may want to check that your app is still in those Accessibility and Full Disk Access lists and if not, add again... and if so, remove it and re-add it.

Comment: @wch1zpink How can I check this? I know where to look for typical apps, but `System Events.app` isn't listed.

Comment: @Jeremy `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility` and `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access` . Make sure you add System Events.app   /System/Library/CoreServices/System Events.app

Answer (score 4):

```
Security & Privacy -> Privacy tab -> Accessibility
```

Add /usr/bin/osascript

> NOTE: You may also need to add your terminal (iTerm in my case)

Comment: The NOTE solved the issue for me: Only after additionally adding "Terminal", the command finally works!

Answer (score 2):

To fix `osascript 1002 permission issue.`

Got to Security & Privacy -> Privacy tab -> Accessibility -> Add osascript (/usr/bin/osascript)

Or Use `NSAppleScript`

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you! In case others have this same problem, in order to add `osascript`, I navigated to its directory in terminal and used `open .` to view the directory in finder. Then you can drag the file from that finder window into the window that pops up when you click the `+` in the system preferences location mentioned by @Parag Bafna.

Comment: **UPDATE:** This worked the first time that I ran the code, but it stopped working after that (I literally only stopped the app and restarted it). I now get the same error, even though `osascript` still shows that it has permission to control my computer. Ideas?

Comment: Do you see app selected in Accessibility or is it unchecked?

Comment: In Security & Privacy -> Privacy tab -> Accessibility, my app is checked. In Security & Privacy -> Privacy tab -> Automation, it has permission to control Spotify, System Events, and itself (toggling that last switch has no effect).

Answer (score 0):

This is a couple of things for you to consider, more than a real answer to your question. If you'd like more details, I'll happily edit them in on request. (also, I'll put code examples in objective-C, because I'm still learning swift)

First, if you're going to be doing a lot of scripting in your app, it may be worth your while to switch over to [Scripting Bridge](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scriptingbridge?language=objc). Scripting Bridge is a cocoa interface for applescripting other apps, so (to steal an example I found elsewhere) if you want to get the name of the current track in iTunes, you'd do something like:

```
iTuneApplication *iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];
currentTrack = iTunes.currentTrack.name;
```

If you want specific code for Spotify I'll have to install that app; let me know.

Second, if you want to do keystrokes, you should look into [Quartz Event Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_event_services?language=objc). QES allows you to create, send, and capture input events. So if you want to send a ⌘C, you might do something like:

```
// '8' is the key code for 'c'
comCDownEvent = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(nil, 8, true); 
CGEventSetFlags(comCDownEvent, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
comCUpEvent = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(nil, 8, false); 
CGEventSetFlags(comCUpEvent, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
CGEventPostToPSN(targetAppProcessSerialNumber, comCDownEvent);
CGEventPostToPSN(targetAppProcessSerialNumber, comCUpEvent);
```

You can't run this code from sandboxed apps, but I think you'll have that problem any way you go.

The main advantage of these approaches is that they avoid switching contexts: it's all done from cocoa, so you don't need to invoke a shell or create an AppleScript environment, and avoid all the translation problems that involves.

Comment: So both examples there are in objective-C?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure how different that is in the second case, thought.

Answer (score 0):

I made an AppleScript that threw this error, and got around it by enabling AEServer in Privacy & Security, Accessibility, on macOS 13.2.1 (Ventura).

According to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/403109/what-is-aeserver-and-why-is-it-requesting-macos-accessibility-permissions):

> AEServer is the Apple Events Server. It is used to control Apple Events that come in from other Macs.

... so I'm not sure if that is something that is safe to do... but it worked for me.